# Cosmos DB provisioned throughput calculation

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a database with enabled option "Provision database throughput".
I chose 400 RUs as my throughput.
If I have 25 collections in my database, does it mean that they will share 400 RUs between each other or it means that the database has 10,000RUs (400RUs * 25 containers)  that will be shared between all containers?

I've read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput) about provisioned throughput on MSDN, but it still unclear for me. How many throughput capacities I have in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the former. The total throughput is 400 RU/s shared across all 25 containers.